# Issue with rotation of a span tag

Tags: html, css

I have the following inline CSS, but I am not able to rotate the arrow with position static.

I need to rotate the HTML arrow. How to fix it?

Notes: I would prefer do not use `position: absolute` if possible.

```html
<span style="transform: rotate(57deg);">➤</span>
```

Comment: `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 4):

See [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#propdef-transform):

> Applies to:   transformable elements
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display
>     property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group,
>     table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS21]
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, patternTransform or
>     gradientTransform [SVG11].

You are using a span, which isn't SVG so the second of those doesn't apply.

A span is, by default, `display: inline`, so it doesn't match any of the first category options either.

Set the `display` property to one of the values listed as acceptable.

```css
body { margin-top: 70px; }
```

```html
<span style="transform: rotate(57deg); display: block; width: 20px; outline: solid red 1px;">➤</span>
```